# Does same cross product imply equality of two vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, cross-product

Does the following implication always hold?

$$\bf{a\times c=b \times c} \implies a=b$$

Comment: This doesn't even hold in real numbers. Have you tried some numerical examples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
a\times c = b\times c \;\; \Longrightarrow \;\; (a-b)\times c = 0
\;\; \Longrightarrow \;\;  c=0 \;\lor\;\exists \lambda : a-b = \lambda c
$$
All we can say is that either $c=0$ or the difference of $a$ and $b$ is collinear with $c$.